# Laravel hasMany() relationship not getting values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have three tables: customers, orders and books. Orders store customers id and books store orders id.

To list orders item on customer page, I add this method to customer model:

```
public function customerOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'id_customer');
}
```

Works fine.

Now I need to grab books for each order. So I add this method to order model:

```
public function orderBooks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderBooks', 'id_order');
}
```

When I try to get orderBooks info inside a loop:

```
@foreach($customer->customerOrders as $order)
...
{{ $order->orderBooks->id }}
...
```

Laravel return

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

How I'm sending data to view:

```
return view('register.customers.show', compact('customer'));
```

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('id_customer')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_customer')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('set null');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('id_order')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_order')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('set null');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your migrations so we can double check this against your database layout?

Comment: See @Pourbahrami's solution below.  That would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@foreach($customer->customerOrders as $order)
    @foreach($order->orderBooks as $book)
        {{ $book->id }}
    @endif
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

is happening because you're trying to get a `id` from a collection, you want the `id` from the objects inside the collection

Try this instead:

```
@foreach($customer->customerOrders->orderBooks as $book)
{{ $book->id }}
@endforeach
```